# Vectorizing calculation of slew rate envelope

Tags: python, numpy

I am working in a problem where for many stored signals (hundreds of thousands), I need to compute the slew-limited version of each signal. The slew-limited version will start with the same initial value as the original signal and try to follow the original signal, but it's rate of change is limited. An inefficient algorithm can be simply expressed as:

```py
import numpy as np

# slew_limit_top is a positive number
# slew_limit_bot is a negative number
def slew_limited(array, slew_limit_top, slew_limit_bot):
  result= np.zeros_like(array)
  result[0] = array[0]
  for idx in range(1, np.size(array)):
    change = array[i] - result[i-1]
    change = min(change, slew_limit_top)
    change = max(change, slew_limit_bot)
    result[i] = result[i-1] + change
  return result
```

Is there a way to vectorize this problem? Or is it intrinsically serial in nature?

---

Edit:

This does not work:

```py
def slew_limited_bad(array, slew_limit_top, slew_limit_bot):
  result = np.diff(array)
  result = np.maximum(result, slew_limit_bot)
  result = np.minimum(result, slew_limit_top)
  result = np.concatenate(([array[0]], result,))
  result = np.cumsum(result)
  return result
```

Because the slope (slew) to limit is not the derivative of the original signal, but the difference between the slew-limited signal so-far and the original signal (the `change` variable in the `slew_limited` function). So the problem is still dependent on itself in a serial fashion.

[image: Serial function vs a vectorization that does not work]

Comment: I feel like you could use np.diff() to do the difference calculation, then use np.cumsum() to do the total change, and then add result[0] to the total change.

Comment: @Baddioes: I think you need to put some thresholding after the `diff()` operation, otherwise  `cumsum()` will simply undo `diff()`. But I agree, `diff()`  is probably the way to start here.

Comment: @JuanBozzo: I think the best stagey here will depend a lot on the statistical properties of the problem. How often do the problem occur, is it randomly distributed or does it come in chunks, what's the ratio of the slew rate per sample to the max value of the signal etc. Characterizing these roughly, will help you find the best solution .

Comment: @Hilmar I should’ve been more specific, but I believe the min() and max() lines would work in vectorized operation as is, right?

Comment: @Himar, @Baddioes, I've tried using `diff` and clamping by `min`/`max`. The issue is that when the slew-limited function "looses track" of the original function, then the `diff` does not longer applies to the original function, but to the difference between the original function and the `cumsum` of the diff up to that point.

@Baddioes: I still don't have hard numbers on the statistics, but a separation should occur at least dozens of times in a signal of ~1000 samples in length